# How to fetch file from remote content based on partial file name?

Tags: linux, unix

I have some sub folders ( A, B , C ,D .. ) in a remote server which contains around 100.gz files . The file naming pattern is like ND2_58_20151105173030_20151105173240_1234.log.gz where 3-rd and 4-th field after _ is the start and end time . Now if the start time / end time is with 15mins from the current time I want to fetch that file .Can anybody suggest me how to do it using shell script.For fetching data I am using rsync .

Thanks ,
Arn

Comment: Could you please share the rsync command? Obfuscate sensitive data if any.

Comment: As of now I am using the 'rsync -avhe "ssh -p $portno" --exclude="/D/*/data1" --exclude-from="$FileNameList" --progress --log-file="$LogFullPath" $User\@$ServerIP:$FolderPath1 $InputFolderPath1 ' . But it doesn't contain the required logic . I can get start time / end time by the below mentioned command cd ~/Downloads/development/20151101
find -maxdepth 2 -name "*.gz" | awk -F _ '{print $3}' >> ${LogFullPath} . But I am not able to fetch files based on the starting time after comparing with current time stamp.

Comment: In `awk` better `print $3,$4, $0` so when you parse you will have the full name ready in the second column. You need `$4` too if it started long ago and ended only few minutes ago...

Comment: Thanks Hastur , yes , you are right . I have to consider both start time and end time .But after getting those start time and end time shall I put it in a log file and then compare with current time stamp ? As I mentioned there are around 10 sub folders which contains around 200 files each and have to fetch those files in same structure of remote server to local server .Added with that all the fetching should be completed by max 3 mins.

Comment: Do a little script. Once you do a list of files/paths, you can parse it within few seconds. In bash once you put a filename (remember `basename`) in a variable, e.g. `fname`, with `a=${fname#*_*_}` you select `20151105173030_20151105173240_1234.log.gz` with `b=${a%_*_*}` you shrink it to `20151105173030` with `year=${b:0:4}` you have `2015` and so on... Of course you can find more cosy way... [Bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: `awk -F_ '{print substr($3,9,13)}'` (and / or "$4", you have to figure out how to do that in detail), then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3675543/5494004

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--include` and `--exclude` options for `rsync` to select only the files you want. If I understand your question correctly, you want the files whose name contains the current date/time plus or minus 15 minutes. Not sure if you need *exactly* 15 minutes, but here's a little script that can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

format='%Y%m%d%H%M'

for delta in $(seq -15 15); do
    p='--include=*_'$(date +$format --date "+ $delta minutes")'*_*.gz'
    include="$include $p"
done

rsync -av $include --exclude=* SRC/ DEST/
```

Should be easy to modify for *exactly* 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes , Kevin you are right . I have to fetch those data only which contains starting time < 15 mins from the current time stamp . Added with that I have to fetch those files from multiple sub folder and source destination folder structure should also be in sync . I will make use of your code ..Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Kevin,I am trying to use your code .But not able to include desired files generated in last 15mins.code. format='%Y%m%d%H%M'
for delta in $(seq -15 0);
  do
     p='--include="*_'$(date +$format --date "+ $delta minutes")'*_*.sig.gz"'
     include="$include $p"
  done
 rsync -avhe "ssh -p $portno" --exclude-from="$Et" $include --exclude="*" --progress --log-file="$LogFullPath" $S1User\@$S1IP:$S1FP1 $InpFP1.I am trying to fetch .sig.gz files from the path ND/B1/a1 of remote server( NE7_08_20151108082030_20151108082100_1.sig.gz)and want to replicate same in local server.Could you plz suggest.

Comment: You need to add the wildcard `*` to `include` and `exclude` options as in my answer. `p='--include="*_'$(date +$format --date "+ $delta minutes")'*_*.sig.gz"'` and `--exclude='*'` Also I don't know `$Et` is, but it should be a file with a list of exclude patterns.

Comment: Hi Kevin , I am using the same wildcard that you have mentioned.Somehow it's not getting reflected here.Yes , as you said "$Et" contains list of sub folder which should be excluded at the time of fetching data and it's working fine. But whenever I am adding $include and --exclude="*" it's not fetching anything .But now I am able to understand the problem.As I have mentioning exclude="*" it's ignoring the directories and not trying to check it's content / naming pattern. Now I have added include="*/" to include the directories and it worked . Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs . .

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the data from the *filesystem* you can use `find` and `rsync` together.

```
find /path -file -mmin +15 -exec rsync {} destination \;
```

or with a reverse logic and only one `rsync` process

```
rsync --files-from=<(find /path -mmin +3 -type f -exec basename {} \;) /src_path/ /dst_path
```

**Reference**

You can give a look to this [answers][[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112407/66388),[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92351/66388),[3](https://serverfault.com/a/642231)], for example...

Comment: Thanks Hastur for your prompt response . But the problem is I can't consider the 15mins earlier data based on time stamp . There may be some scenarios where the time stamp of the file may be different from start / end time . So , I have to compare the partial file name ( end time / start time ) with current TS and then fetch that file from the remote server .

Comment: You're welcome. So you should try to do a _DRY run_ of `rsync -n`, or better a simple `ssh ls /my/src_path`, to parse the output, sed where `sed 's/_/ /g'` needed,  create a list, filter (maybe awk or bash string substitution) and run a second time `rsync` with that one.